# How to imitate same action for back button as in back button of navigation controller using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two navigation controllers as follows:

1. Navigation controller1 -> View controller1
2. Tab view Controller -> Navigation controller2 -> View controller2

When I'm in View controller2 and pressed back button, I want to go to View controller1. It is working fine with built in back button in navigation bar, but when I tried to write my own it doesn't work.

I have tried the following statements but they didn't work:

1. `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`
2. `self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`
3. `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`
4. `let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`

```
    let pushVC = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC1")
    let navigation = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Navigation1") as! UINavigationController
     navigation.pushViewController(VC1!, animated: true)
```

Comment: View controller1 present or push??

Comment: @HimanshuPatel It is Push.

Comment: first time Navigation controller1 -> View controller1 go push to  Navigation controller2 -> View controller2 right?. and than  View controller2 -> View controller1 move right?

Comment: Yes... I want View controller2 -> View controller1 to happen

Answer (score 0):

if you are using navigationController in the first one only then you can use this to navigate to your ViewController2:

```
 let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
    navigationController?.showDetailViewController(vc2, sender: self)
```

Then if you wanna back from viewController2 to ViewController1 you can create cancel button and connect its action and write this in the action:

```
@IBAction func buttonCancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

But if there is a navigationController in both ViewController1 & ViewController2 then you will use the below:

```
 let VC2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
    navigationController?.pushViewController(VC2, animated: true)
```

and you can pop it (Dismiss it):

```
    @IBAction func buttonCancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```